# Previous value of BehaviourSubject

Tags: rxjs

I'm preparing Angular + RxJS app, and I've some question.

I would read previous emitted value of my BehaviourSubject. Is it possible?

Example:

- emit 'one'
- emit 'two'
- now I would get 'one'

Regards

Answer (score 1):

use `pairwise` operator with your behaviour subject.

```
const data= new BehaviroSubject(1)
const pairData=data.pipe(pairwise())
data.next(2)
pairData.subscribe(console.log)
// you should get [1,2]
```